# How to Extract jar from Zip file using java

Tags: java, jar, zip

File Structure

```
Zip file-> web-Inf -> *.jar
```

How to extract the jar from that path?

I am using `asm-tree classReader` to extract methods from jar classes.
If I mentioned the path correctly ,I can read the jar.

Comment: you need to post your codes that you tried and error that you are getting. In absence of that it looks like code for me request...

Answer (score 1):

The [ZipFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) class can be used for working with zip files. Specifically, the method `entries()` returns a List of all entries in the Zip file.

Comment: I don't know the exact path.That's what the problem.

Comment: @karthikj That's why I mentioned the entries() method, iterate through that until you find jar files in the right directory.

Comment: even if I get directory path, I can't read the jar file,it always throw `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: @karthikj How are you trying to read it? The correct way is ZipFile.getInputStream. I assume you try to somehow create a File object out of the ZipEntry? Yeah that won't work. That being said, I found that passing around InputStreams instead of Files or, even worse, file names makes a program a lot easier to test (because you can just plug in a StringReader in your test instead of having to go through the Filesystem)